# Npm package commands stopped working after installing Homebrew on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, homebrew, node-modules

I'm using nodemon for my node.js project and wanted to install MongoDB locally on my Mac which runs Catalina 10.15.7. For that I installed the latest version of Homebrew. I started the MongoDB server sucessfully and connected to it with MongoDB compass.

After that I switched back to my nodejs project and noticed that in my zsh terminal (in Visual Studio Code) I suddenly couldn't use the nodemon command anymore. I get the error:

> zsh: command not found: nodemon

I reinstalled nodemon in the project and globally too but that didn't work. I read that it's a problem with the .zshrc file so I tried to create one with the nano editor and add

> echo 'export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc

but that didn't work either (I tried to replace npm-global with npm-package).

At this point I have no idea where the issue is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but reinstalling nodemon globally with sudo worked somehow.